# Clojurescript async <? macro

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, macros, clojurescript

I keep seeing this macro `<?`, in swanodette's code which looks really useful :

In this [gist](https://gist.github.com/swannodette/6385166) :

```
;; BOOM!!! we can convert async errors into exceptions
(go (try
      (let [x (<? (run-task (.-readFile fs) "foo.txt" "utf8"))]
        (.log js/console "Success" x))
      (catch js/Error e
        (.log js/console "Oops" e))))
```

In this blog post :

```
(go (try
      (let [tweets    (<? (get-tweets-for "swannodette"))
            first-url (<? (expand-url (first (parse-urls tweets))))
            response  (<? (http-get first-url))]
        (. js/console (log "Most recent link text:" response)))
      (catch js/Error e
        (. js/console (error "Error with the twitterverse:" e)))))
```

> `<?` is just a touch of macro sugar that expands into something like
>   (throw-err (`<!` [expr])). In core.async `<!` serves the same purpose as
>   ES6's yield operator. If an asynchronous process writes an error onto
>   its channel we will convert it into an exception.

But I can't find a definition for it. How is it implemented in Clojure{Script} ?

Comment: FYI: All his code is on github: https://github.com/swannodette/swannodette.github.com File you're looking for: `macros.clj` & `helpers.cljs`

Comment: @Andre thanks ! I was looking for that ! (Searching <? on github doesn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so here is what I am using so far. There is probably room for improvement.

In Clojure :

```
(defn throw-err [e]
  (when (instance? Throwable e) (throw e))
  e)

(defmacro <? [ch]
  `(throw-err (<! ~ch)))
```

In ClojureScript :

```
(defn error? [x]
  (instance? js/Error x))


(defn throw-err [e]
  (when (error? e) (throw e))
  e)

(defmacro <? [ch]
  `(throw-err (<! ~ch)))
```

I am completely unsure about the readability of my solution though (`throw-err` looks like it should throw an error, but it doesn't. At least not every time).

Comment: Exceptions inside worker threads don't necessarily do anything to let you know they happened. Stuart Sierra has a good [blog post](http://stuartsierra.com/2015/05/27/clojure-uncaught-exceptions) showing some settings you can establish to ensure you actually see errors in the world of async. "In the JVM, when an exception is thrown on a thread other than the main thread, and nothing is there to catch it, nothing happens. The thread dies silently."

Comment: Is it necessary for <? to be a macro?

Comment: Answering my own question, yes, it can't be a function, because <! must be inside a go block.